# Split views.py in several files

Tags: python, django

My `views.py` has become too big and it's hard to find the right view.

How do I split it in several files and then import it? Does it involve any speed loss?

Can I do the same with `models.py`?

Comment: I split my large (7k lines) views.py file to separate files and the increase in speed was significant.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

In Django everything is a Python module (*.py). You can create a view folder with an `__init__.py` inside and you still will be able to import your views, because this also implements a Python module. But an example would be better.

Your original `views.py` might look like this :

```
def view1(arg):
    pass

def view2(arg):
   pass
```

With the following folder/file structure it will work the same :

```
views/
   __init__.py
   viewsa.py
   viewsb.py
```

`viewsa.py` :

```
def view1(arg):
    pass
```

`viewsb.py` :

```
def view2(arg):
    pass
```

`__init__.py` :

```
from viewsa import view1
from viewsb import view2
```

The *quick* explanation would be: when you write `from views import view1` Python will look for view1 in

1. `views.py`, which is what happens in the first (original) case
2. `views/__init__.py`, which is what happens in the second case. Here, `__init__.py` is able to provide the view1 method because it imports it.

With this kind of solution, you might have no need to change `import` or `urlpattern`s arguments in `urls.py`

If you have many methods in each new view file, you might find it useful to make the imports in `views/__init__.py` use `*`, like this:

```
from viewsa import *
from viewsb import *
```

I actually don't know about speed issues (but I doubt there are any).

For Models it might be a bit difficult.

Comment: Could you please add a url pattern that matches view1 or view2 in your example? Because I'm having issues with that....

Comment: I tried doing this, but when I go to import my models (from app.models import MyModel or from models import MyModel) Python complains that the model doesn't exist.

Comment: It is ok if we delete the views.py in root directory?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me (same error than for @ChrisMiller. My solution: in `__init__.py`: `from myapp.views.viewsa import *`. Note that you can't have a views.py anymore (or at least it won't be read @ShiftNTab: Error for not finding your views in views.py). Hope it helps!

Comment: What about the naming convention: should the file name be singular or plural? E.g: `views.car.py` vs `views.cars.py`

Comment: I had to use a period: from .viewsa import * -- it might be worth correcting the answer if this is a general problem/solution.

Answer (score 24):

I've had to do this before (for clarities sake)

The way I did this was to create a `views` directory, then, in that, create a file called `__init__.py`

Now, when you're calling in your `urls.py`, you simply need to add another part

For example, previously, you may have called:-

```
url(r'^calendar/(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)/$', 'myproject.calendar.views.year')
url(r'^calendar/(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)/(?P<user>[a-z]+)/$', 'myproject.calendar.views.year_by_user')
```

You can now call something along the lines of

```
url(r'^calendar/(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)/$', 'myproject.calendar.views.year.index')
url(r'^calendar/(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)/(?P<user>[a-z]+)/$', 'myproject.calendar.views.year.user')
```

This is, of course, assuming that you had `views/year.py` containing the functions `index` and `user` ;)

Answer (score 17):

Just for sharing, I had a bit of issues with Vincent Demeester's answer. Everything is fine except in **init**.py file, I have to write in this way:

**__init__.py**:

```
from .viewsa import *
from .viewsb import *
```

This way I still don't need to change my `import` method in urls.py. I am on *Python 3.6.1* and *Django 1.11.4*.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, you can put your code, whereever you wish. Just make sure, you change the import statements accordingly, e.g. for the views in the `urls.py`.

Not knowing your actual code its hard to suggest something meaningful. Maybe you can use some kind of filename prefix, e.g. `views_helper.py`, `views_fancy.py`, `views_that_are_not_so_often_used.py` or so ...

Another option would be to create a `views` directory with an `__init__.py`, where you import all *subviews*. If you have a need for a large number of files, you can create more nested subviews as your views grow ...

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer: Yes.

Best is to make a directory called views and then in your urls.py do:

```
import views
...
url(r'^classroom$', views.school.klass, name="classroom"),
```

Answer (score 2):

[Vincent Demeester](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921911/5046652)'s answer is superb! but for me [addicted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46108146/5046652)'s answer worked like a charm. 
I faced difficulties in **migrating** database. The error indicates the line where the first model is imported and says could not recognize my app module. Searched a lot but could not find a solution but later on I imported the model like this:

```
from ..models import ModelName
```

**It worked!!**

Answer (score 1):

Since Django just expects a view to be a callable object, you can put then wherever you like in your PYTHONPATH. So you could for instance just make a new package myapp.views and put views into multiple modules there. You will naturally have to update your urls.py and other modules that reference these view callables.

Comment: This is actually incorrect - it can be done with models. See: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4470

Comment: Ah, good to know, thank you :-) I always thought there was a bit more magic involved with models and how they live in the app package. Removed the line about models in my response.

Comment: Glad I could help, I realized later that this link actually explains how it's done with models much better: http://blog.amber.org/2009/01/19/moving-django-models-into-their-own-module/

Answer (score 1):

I split almost all views in my apps into a views folder (with an **init**.py of course).  I do not, however, import all of the subviews in the **init**.py like some of the answers have suggested.  It seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with putting this in my **init**.py:

```
import os

currPath = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

dirFiles = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currPath):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.py') and not name.startswith('_'): 
            dirFiles.append(name.strip('.py'))

for f in dirFiles:
    exec("from %s import %s" % (f,f))
```

I'm still new to python, so I'm still looking at what effect it has on speed/security/ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you have a file named: `password_generator.py` then inside `views.py` add: `from password_generator import *`

Then you can call that module's function from `views.py`.