# Shifting thinking from CakePHP to Django - a monolithic views file?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-views

I'm trying to get started with Django, and have previously worked with CakePHP, and so my MVC background comes out of that.  I'm aware of Django's slightly different MTV architecture, and am fine with the monolithic model files - multiple classes in one file I can handle just fine.

But I'm confused about how to do the views (which are roughly analagous to controllers in MVC, correct?).  The examples I've seen just have one `views.py` that has methods like `index()`, `view()`, etc.  But if I have a bunch of users that create and own widgets that they can share, for example, I want to have `/users/view` that runs `view()` for the users model, and `/widgets/view` that runs `view()` for the widgets model.

I don't see any way to separate those out, and don't know what the correct/conventional/right way is to do so.  I may just be having trouble wrapping my head around Django's way of doing things, too.  Should I have methods in `view.py` that are `user_view` and `widget_view`?  That seems very clunky.

Or should I have `user_view.py` or even `user/view.py` that contains `index()` and `view()`?  Could I reference those from the URL routing?  How are things generally done with Django and this kind of thing?

This may ultimately be related to (or even solved by) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files), but I'm asking more as a question of what convention and the right way to think about such things is.

Additionally, shouldn't the docs/examples be clearer on this?  I've been impressed by the docs thus far, but I'm pretty sure most web apps will deal with more than one "object," and it seems to me that this would come up pretty often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python view files are just Python modules. The views themselves are just functions that can live anywhere you like - the module doesn't even have to be called `views.py`. The urlconf (in `urls.py`) can refer to views anywhere at all.

One obvious way of separating things out is into separate applications, which is covered well in the documentation - you can also have separate urls.py files for each app and use `include` in the main site-level urls.py to include all the sub-files.

But there's nothing to stop you sub-dividing the views in a single app into multiple files - eg by creating a `views` module, containing a (blank) `__init__.py` and as many other view files as you like.

Or, if you really do have views associated only with a particular model - and you'd be surprised how seldom that is the case - again, you could make your views classmethods on the model class itself. All a view has to do is to accept a request, and any other parameters, and return a response.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still getting used to the flexibility that Django offers, I think.  I noticed the docs about separate applications, but I'm looking within an app, so having the possibility of splitting them is good to have.