# Breaking Django views into seperate directories and files

Tags: django, django-views

I'm quite new to Django and I'm enjoying it a lot. I have broken my app's views into different files and placed them in a directory called app/views/(view files).

I have made an `__init__.py` file in the views directory this has caused me to have to use `myproj.app.views.views` in my site code. Which of coarse not very digestible.

Any ideas around this. Or is renaming my views directory to something else the way forward.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have so many views that you need to slit them across different files that might be a sign that your application does too much things. Consider splitting your full app into several apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: split views.py in several files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just import the views from the other modules in `__init__.py`.

Comment: So inside `__init__.py` I simply put `import views` ?

Comment: `from .views import view1, view2, ...`

Answer (score 0):

My user profile app `account` has three views files: `views.py`, `views_login.py`, and `views_profile.py`.  Maybe it's not the cleanest, but it separates the three parts of `account` pretty well for my needs.  My `apps/account/urls.py` therefore looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo1$', 'apps.account.views.foo1'),
    (r'^foo2$', 'apps.account.views.foo2'),
    (r'^bar1$', 'apps.account.views_login.bar1'),
    (r'^bar2$', 'apps.account.views_login.bar2'),
    (r'^baz1$', 'apps.account.views_profile.baz1'),
    (r'^baz2$', 'apps.account.views_profile.baz2'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks. As  Skirmantas stated above I think I have to much going on in my app. it should broken up more.