# Can a django app have more than one views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have just started learning Django. I was wondering if Django app can have more than one views file? Let's say, I have two separate classes. Should I keep them in one views file or can I make two views files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files

Comment: Two classes can be in the same file though. This is not Java :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are just python modules, you can do whatever you want, for instance you can change their names to `whatever.py` as long as your `imports` are correct :)

And as suggested: find more info here [Django: split views.py in several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files) :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. A modular way of splitting would be to create a package -  `views/`

```
- views/
    - first.py
    - second.py
    - __init__.py
```

and in your `__init.py__` add the following:

```
from .first import *
from .second import *
```

This way, all your views would be available for `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that, it is only a convention to use `views.py`.

Now, the question is: do you really need to create a new file to put your views inside ? Shouldn't these regrouped in a new application ?

Think of an other person reviewing your code: would the reason of the separation be crystal clear to him ?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to separate it because I have two separate classes. One is just for validating the form data and redirecting and the other is to make reservation with the form data. I am building a reservation application.

Comment: Do you think this is a bad django practice?