# split views.py into multiple files

Tags: django

I am having some trouble splitting my `views.py` file into multiple files in a views folder. I tried the methods from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files), but I keep getting an error message.

file structure:

```
users/
   __init__.py
   urls.py
   views/
      __init__.py
      sign_in_out_up.py
```

urls.py:

```
from users import views as user

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^signup/', user.sign_in_out_up.signup),
    url(r'^signin/', user.sign_in_out_up.signin),
    url(r'^signout/', user.sign_in_out_up.signout),
)
```

When I try the above code, I get an error saying `'module' object has no attribute 'sign_in_out_up'`.

I have tried `users.views.sign_in_out_up.signup` in `urls.py`, but then the error changes to `name 'users' is not defined`, which seems to be a step backwards.

I have also tried putting `from sign_in_out_up import *` in `views/__init__.py`

Has anyone else had problems with this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write your code in `urls.py` as normal (i.e., import the view from that `views` module as if it were `views.py`) and add to `__init__.py` within `views`:

```
from sign_in_out_up import *
```

This ensures you can continue to split up views in the `views` module without having to update `urls.py` all the time.

Comment: I still get an error saying "cannot import name views". The error point to the line in urls.py where I try to import the view

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
from .sign_in_out_up import *
```

in `views/__init__.py` instead.

Add `'.'` before `'sign_in_out_up'`.