# How to handle a big views.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I referred [Django: split views.py in several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files) but the question was asked in 2009

How to handle a very big views.py in Django 1.7. Is there any new pattern evolved after 2009 to solve this?

Comment: No there isn't. Is there anything wrong with the approach outlined in that question?

Comment: that is still a valid approach - make `views.py` a package and add individual views into their own modules. Also I would recommend to use class-based-views if you have lots of common code between the views since CBV allow to combine all of the common functionality into base classes which can be easily reused.