# Django unable to split views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-1.8

I have recently started adopting Python and the Django framework. There are numerous things that are awesome about it and also numerous things that I really hate. One of those things is having one `views.py` file per Django app, which I find just really unpractical. So I decided to split my views into multiple files. It has proven to be much more difficult than I originally thought.

I followed lot of questions and tutorials  but none of them work. I should add that I am using Python 3.4 on ArchLinux and Django 1.8.

My original setup (I have simplified it, there actually are more view functions):

views.py

```
def entries(request):
    ...

def delete_entry(request, id):
    ...

def categories(request):
    ...

def delete_category(request, id):
    ...
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from transactions import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^entries$', views.entries, name='entries'),
    url(r'^delete_entry(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/)?$', views.delete_entry, name='delete_entry'),

    url(r'^categories$', views.categories, name='categories'),
    url(r'^delete_category(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/)?$', views.delete_category, name='delete_category'),
)
```

My desired state is:

views folder containing entries.py and categories.py:

**Edit:** There **is** an **init**.py file in the views folder.

entries.py

```
def entries(request):
    ...

def delete_entry(request, id):
    ...
```

categories.py

```
same logic as above
```

urls.py that I am using with this setup:

```
from transactions.views import entries, categories
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^entries$', entries.entries, name='entries'),
    url(r'^delete_entry(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/)?$', entries.delete_entry, name='delete_entry'),

    url(r'^categories$', categories.categories, name='categories'),
    url(r'^delete_category(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/)?$', categories.delete_category, name='delete_category'),
)
```

when I try to `manage.py runserver`, an `ViewDoesNotExists` error is raised with `Could not import 'transactions.views.entries'. View is not callable.` message. When I try to dump `entries.entries` in `urls.py`, it actually is a function, same as with the original setup.

So far I have tried numerous suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files) question such as import variants, hacking `__init.py__` in views folder, using views folder without `__init__.py`, but the results are pretty much the same or there are import errors.

Comment: Do you have a file named `__init__.py` in the `views` folder?

Comment: put `__init__.py` in views folder.

Comment: The error `Could not import 'transactions.views.entries'` does not match up with your new urls.py and views layout. Make sure you have deleted any old pyc files, and restart your server as well.

Comment: @giaosudau I'm sorry for late response, wasn't at my PC for some time. I do have an __init__.py file in the views dir (tried with and without it, tried importing views in __init__.py, none worked).

Comment: @Alasdair I tried removing all *.pyc files in the project and all pycache directories. Still no luck - same error. It is weird to me too that the path is for the module, not the function. If I try to dump entries.entries, it correctly shows <function entries at ...>

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. I do note that you've posted simplified code, not the real code, so that could be hiding the problem. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks anyway! I have actually figured out the problem now and found out it was my own fault - I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some time and found out that the fault is between my keyboard and chair :-). The problem is not with the urls.py in my transactions app, but in the "main" app django creates for you where you import the urls.py from other apps. I have left there one url for transactions.views.entries and forgot it there, so it was complaining for this file and I haven't seen it.

For anyone having similar issues - check yout main urls.py too!

Thanks everyone for their answers and comments.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like "one views.py file per Django app". The `startapp` command simply creates a views.py file for you, just for the sake of putting the code somewhere. A view function can live anywhere as long as it is on your Python path. What this means is that it has to be importable so as the comments suggest you might be missing `__init__.py` in your `views` folder.

> [Writing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/)
>
> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that
> takes a Web request and returns a Web response. This response can be
> the HTML contents of a Web page, or a redirect, or a 404 error, or an
> XML document, or an image . . . or anything, really. The view itself
> contains whatever arbitrary logic is necessary to return that
> response. This code can live anywhere you want, as long as it’s on
> your Python path. There’s no other requirement–no “magic,” so to
> speak. For the sake of putting the code somewhere, the convention is
> to put views in a file called views.py, placed in your project or
> application directory.

Comment: Also, I would recommend importing all views into the `__init__.py` so as to abstract out the actual layout of the views. For instance, I believe the urlconf file should just be importing `myapp.views` and not know about the underlying files.

Comment: I do have an __init__.py file (sorry that was not clear) and I also tried to do the imports in init file, but that did not work either - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the views into the urls.py, you could try something like this.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^entries$', 'transactions.views.entries.entries', name='entries'),
    url(r'^delete_entry(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/)?$', 'transactions.views.entries.delete_entry', name='delete_entry'),

    url(r'^categories$', 'transactions.views.categories.categories', name='categories'),
    url(r'^delete_category(?:/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/)?$', 'transactions.views.categories.delete_category', name='delete_category'),
)
```

Comment: Support for string view arguments [is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#url), so I wouldn't recommend it for new projects.

Comment: I have tried this, but no luck, still the same message :-(