# in django app when splitting view.py file I am getting issues with url.py

Tags: python, django

So my view file got huge and i decided to split it to smaller parts
following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files)

I created a views folder and under this folder created few view...py files

What ever was existing is still works after splitting but now when i try to create a new view files I am getting issues in url file

this is my `_init_.py` file located in my view folder

```
from views import *
from viewscategory import * 
from viewssubcategory import *
from viewsitemgroup import *
from viewsmaterial import *
from viewsbomversion import *
from viewsbom import *
from viewsapprovedmanufacture import *
```

This my url file relevant part

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include,patterns
import item.views
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('item.views',

    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_new, name="approvedmanufacture_new"),
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_edit, name="approvedmanufacture_edit"),
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_delete, name="approvedmanufacture_delete"),
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/approvedmanufacture_details/(?P<pk>\d+)$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_details, name="approvedmanufacture_details"),
)
```

and  this is the error from terminal

```
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\item\urls.py", line 58, in <module>
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.appro
vedmanufacture_new, name="approvedmanufacture_new"),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'approvedmanufacture_new'
[03/May/2016 17:51:10]"GET /item/material/material_bomversion_details/3 HTTP/1.1
" 500 59
```

Even if I modify my line in ulr.py to include full path I  am still getting same error

```
url(r'^approvedmanufacture/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.viewsapprovedmanufacture.approvedmanufacture_new, name="approvedmanufacture_new"),
```

or

```
url(r'^approvedmanufacture/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.viewsapprovedmanufacture.approvedmanufacture_new, name="approvedmanufacture_new"),
```

The funny thing in the same file I have 2 views:

-def material_bomversion_details 
i had this one before I made the split

and new one 
   -def material_am_details

so when in shell I execute 
from item.views import  material_bomversion_details it runs ok, 
but when I execute from item.views import material_am_details  .

I am getting ImportError: cannot import name material_am_details

This is beyond my understanding 
It looks like there is some kind of cache in Django framework that saved ok everything that was there before the split and is not adding anything new to it . After moving everything back to one view file everything works just fine.

Comment: Did you create a `views` folder? Your question says `view`.

Comment: I created views folder.

Comment: In the shell, can you do `from item.views import *` or does it give an error?

Comment: No,  I am  not getting an error.

Comment: does your views folder have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes,  this is what I mentioned in my question

Comment: Is it actually named `__init__.py` (2x double underscores), or is it named `_init_.py` like in your question?

Comment: it was named with one underscore only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `views/__init__.py`, you can fix this issue by importing views relatively:

```
from .viewscategory import * 
from .viewssubcategory import *
from .viewsitemgroup import *
from .viewsmaterial import *
from .viewsbomversion import *
from .viewsbom import *
from .viewsapprovedmanufacture import *
```

And then in your urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from item import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_new, name="approvedmanufacture_new"),
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_edit, name="approvedmanufacture_edit"),
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_delete, name="approvedmanufacture_delete"),
    url(r'^approvedmanufacture/approvedmanufacture_details/(?P<pk>\d+)$', item.views.approvedmanufacture_details, name="approvedmanufacture_details"),
]
```