# Django/Python: Import once, use everywhere

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have the following structure for my `views` directory.

```
views
|--__init__.py
|--a_management.py
|--b_management.py
|--c_management.py
|--d_management.py
|--e_management.py
```

and `__init__.py` starts with the following:

```
from a_management import *
from b_management import *
from c_management import *
from d_management import *
from e_management import *
.........
...etc...
.........
```

In each of the files (`a_management.py`,`b_management.py`...) I need to write the same code importing modules:

```
import sys,os
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
.........
...etc...
.........
```

Is it possible to perform all the module imports only in `__init__.py`?

When I tried, it still seems like the imports are not found and I get errors like: `NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined`

Comment: I'm very confused by your choice of structure. Why are you importing all of your in `__init__.py`, where else are you using them?

Comment: @IanAuld I'm following this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1921911) to split up `views.py`

Comment: Splitting up view functions/methods is fine. However importing a view to use somewhere else is somewhat unusual unless that place is your `urls.py`. Adding all your views to init just makes it so you use `from views import SomeView` instead of `from view.a_management import SomeView`. You don't actually have to add anything to `__init__.py` to create a package.

Comment: @IanAuld I believe I may have been unclear in the question. I'm not importing `views` anywhere else, I'm just trying to avoid having to write duplicate code importing the same modules (`sys`,`os`, `django-auth` etc.) within each view file.

Comment: Then adding your views to init is doing nothing for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a shared script to do all the system imports?

BTW, I agree that `import *` is not the greatest of idea.  It makes sense in my use of **importer**, but I am not so sure in your general setup.  Also, you need to careful about circular imports.

So, my answer is specifically only geared towards *I need to write the same code importing modules:*, not towards whether your setup as a whole makes sense.

Proof of concept, **importer** is what you really care about.:

```
├── pack
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── importer.py
│   ├── mgmt_1.py
│   ├── mgmt_2.py
└── test.py
```

**test.py**

```
import pack
pack.foo_1()
pack.foo_2()
```

**init.py**
    from mgmt_1 import *
    from mgmt_2 import *

**mgmt_1.py**

```
from .importer import *

print "sys", sys
print "os", os

def foo_1():
    print "foo_1"
```

**mgmt_2.py:**

```
from .importer import *

print "sys", sys
print "os", os

def foo_2():
    print "foo_2", dir(sys)[0:5]
```

**importer.py**

```
import sys
import os
```

output:

```
sys <module 'sys' (built-in)>
os <module 'os' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
sys <module 'sys' (built-in)>
os <module 'os' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
foo_1
foo_2:sys ['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Answer (score 3):

If each `management` module needs access to `sys`, then they all must import it.  No way around that.  (And really, if they all need it, then they all *should* import it.  It's not a bad thing.)

You could save a bit of typing by having `__init__` import `sys`, `os` and whtever else is needed, and then each `management` module can do `from __init__ import *`, thus "inheriting" all the imported modules from `__init__`.

Well, except you can't do it this way, because `__init__` already imports stuff from the `management` modules, so the above suggestion would result in circular imports, which are a no-no.

I don't know the specifics of your application, but I have to believe that there's a better way to organize your modules to avoid so much repeated importing, and especially so much use of `import *`.  Generally you want to use that as little as possible.

Comment: Sounds like I can create an `common_imports.py` and then use `from common_imports import *`? EDIT: That works !!

Comment: Definitely don't do that, I would even go as far as saying that is an anti-pattern. Your imports should be at the top of the file they are used in not squirled away in some other file. If your views are all importing the same modules think if you can abstract away some repeated code in to shared functions. Create a new file, move repeated code there in to smaller functions, do your repeated imports there and then only import the functions you need.

Comment: Okay... that makes sense... @IanAuld. JSIK, why is this frowned upon?

Comment: Namespacing. When you use `import *` it imports everything. As an example, if there a variable/function that has the name `foo` in `a_management.py` and one named `foo` in `b_management.py` (this happens all the time and isn't itself a bad practice). When you do `from views import *`, which `foo` are you now using? One is going to overwrite the other and you won't know until run time which one. Being explicit is better than implicit. IT will make your code much more maintainable. You might remember today what's in common_imports but might not in 6 months.

Comment: That also seems like a hard to diagnose circular import waiting to happen.