# Can't split django views into subfolders

Tags: python, django

I'm following the directions from the first answer here:

[Django: split views.py in several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/django-split-views-py-in-several-files)

I created a 'views' folder in my app and moved my views.py file inside and renamed it to viewsa.py. I also created an **init**.py file in the 'views' folder.

My folder structure:

```
myproject/
    myproject/
        ...
        ...
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        views/
            __init__.py
            viewsa.py
```

The first problem is in myapp/views/**init**.py I tried to do this:

```
from viewsa import *
```

and I get an "unresolved reference viewsa" error

I *can* however do this in the same file instead (in other words, it doesn't throw an error):

```
from . import viewsa
```

But I can't find any way to import these sub directory views into myapp/urls.py even following the directions in the link above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative import, in your `__init__.py`:

```
from .viewsa import *
```

(notice the dot in `.viewsa`)

Comment: Interesting, and I assume I have to do that same syntax in the myapp/urls.py file when importing my views subdirectory? Is this necessary only in python3? Can you explain why its necessary?

Comment: This is required in python3 only. With python 2.7 from viewsa import * will do, I've just checked

Comment: If you import * from vievsa in `views/__init__.py` you'll be able to use `from myapp.views import ...` in your `urls.py` as before.

Comment: Thanks. Saved me a lot of frustration :)