# ImportError: No module named models after split views.py into several files

Tags: python, django

I am doing the same thing as the following question. the top answer is what I did.

[Split views.py in several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921771/split-views-py-in-several-files)

However, when I go to import my models

```
from .models import MyModel
```

I get this error:
ImportError: No module named models

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your directory structure it's not possible to give you an exact answer but you almost definitely moved your newly split apart `views.py` into a `views/` directory which means that the relative reference has been broken. Try this

```
from ..models import MyModel
```

which means go one directory up the tree.

Also, make sure that there's an `__init__.py` file in your `views/` directory. Fine if it's blank.

Comment: I read some articles saying that python does not allow to import from parent directory. why?   like what it says here, https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#case-4-importing-from-parent-directory